# Why is advancement in Demon Hunters capped at d12?

Tags: character-advancement, demon-hunters-rpg

Is there a particular reason to cap advancement at the level of d12?

In contrast, in Fate Core you can extend your pyramid to new heights for an additional cost. Translating to Demon Hunters terminology, we could allow moving the first die from d12 to d14 (or 14->16, 16->18, ...) if the Significant Milestone is at the same time a Major Milestone.

Granted, d14-d18 are not part of "the" polyhedral dice set but you *can* get them.

Do I break the game if I allow characters to move higher than d12, eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cam Banks, designer of the game, [says](https://www.facebook.com/groups/brotherhoodofthecelestialtorch/permalink/1181797398551599/?comment_id=1184365118294827):

> As for advancement, I have to admit I'm not that interested in blowing out the lid on stats in games like this. I don't treat Demon Hunters like it's a "start as a noob, level up until you're epic" game. Fate's generally not like that, either. I sort of look at most campaigns lasting around 6 months of real time before you start another game (either another DH campaign or another game altogether) and planning for a few years' worth of playing the same set of characters is not as big a goal these days as it was for D&D or the like previously.

So the cap seems to be more of a flavor choice: we don't want super-hero stats and we probably won't follow any given character long enough for the cap to matter, in this universe.

That said, I don't think it's likely anything *breaks* in a mechanical sense if you allow higher dice.